# Why does video footage of walking look unnatural when viewed upside down?

Tags: perception, vision

I noticed this whilst lying on the floor to stretch my back and the TV happened to be on. People look like they're walking in a very unnatural way.

Comment: Somewhat speculative thought is that it is an experience dependent effect.  Almost all of the time you see people walking, it is upright. We know the visual system is sensitive to experience in similar ways with things like faces. I don't know if there is any research in particular on motion inversion.